# Javascript write new javascript links based on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how to write the following, ONLY if window width size is `480` or less.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'idangerous.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'custom.js' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'idangerous.swiper' %>
```

So far what I have is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if (width <= 480) {
    _output.innerHTML = "<%= javascript_include_tag 'idangerous.js' %>";
    _output.innerHTML = "<%= javascript_include_tag 'custom.js' %>";
    _output.innerHTML = "<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'idangerous.swiper' %>";
  }
});
</script>
```

However that doesn't work and I don't want to use `document.write`. I also tried to append in header, but I want this written in the bottom of my page, before `</body>`

Any other simplified solutions that work?

Comment: Tried to append in body?

Comment: `$( "body" ).append();` - Documentation here - http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: no i haven't... good idea, any way to put it at the bottom of all content, like last item in body?

Comment: Yes, they will be appended at the bottom before close tag of body

Comment: Is there a way to write javascript similar to php where you can do <?php if something ?> add text <?php else ?> something else here<?php end; ?>, is there something with java like that based on screen size if? I'm thinking.. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As you can't append script tags as strings (at least not without splitting the string) since the browser HTML parser will see the `</script>` within the string and it will interpret it as the end of the script element, you'll have to create them dynamically

```
if (window.clientWidth <= 480) {
    var scripts = ['idangerous.js', 'custom.js', 'idangerous.swiper'];
    for (var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
        addScript(scripts[i])
    }
}

function addScript(src) {
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = src;
   head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: that would work but doing so, it actually breaks all my other javascripts from functioning. Anyway that I can tell Javascript to put it at the very end of my `<head>` just before `</head>`?

Comment: This does that, it uses appendChild, so it appends, i.e. puts it at the bottom, of the head section.

Comment: Could be the path isn't right, not sure what the native rails function outputs, but it surely outputs the entire script tag, and the closing tag in those strings are going to cause issues as noted in the answer, as it's parsed as a closing script tag by the browser.

Comment: Not sure why, but the first paragraph in my original question, the tags for rails, when I use those, everything works as it should, but loads those 3 on all devices and I need them to only load on 480 or lower screens, using any JS solution, works partially.

Comment: You'll have to inspect the script tags in the console, just remove the condition so it works on all screens, and then see if the script tags are the same as the ones outputted by rails. I believe there is javascript_path in rails that gets you the right path to the files, not sure though.

Comment: inspecting the console, it doesn't even load them... should i be placing your code within the `$(function() {` `});` ? sorry, not a pro at any of this :)

Comment: nope, very strange... if I use any type of JS to write the JS files, it won't work partially it does... however, if I just use the Rails to write it out, works like a charm. Can it be because maybe I should be using a construction for jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: It surely works, just testing in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdBWW/) shows errors in the console as the files aren't found, but that also means the script tags where inserted like they should.

Comment: Right no I know but I'm wondering what's the difference. I'm thinking I can't load them using JavaScript ... I'll give it a try with jquery or figure something else since JavaScript stuff just doesn't fit in this scenario